# Jupyter Hub coding issue

Tags: python, matlab, plot, traceback, jupyterhub

having a bit of trouble with some code here and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I created my first plot using a dataframe and wrote the code like this (it accurately produced the plot I needed):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot('Pressure_kPa', 'Height_m', data = mississauga)
plt.xlabel('Air Pressure (kPa)', fontsize = 16)
plt.ylabel('Height (m)', fontsize = 16)
plt.title('Air Pressure by Altitude', fontsize = 16)
```

But then, when I try and do the same thing with different variables (also accurately labeled):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot('Density_kg/m-3', 'Height_m', data = mississauga)
plt.xlabel('Air Density (kg m^3)', fontsize = 16)
plt.ylabel('Height (m)', fontsize = 16)
plt.title('Air Density by Altitude', fontsize = 16)
```

### I get this:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[52], line 6
      2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      4 # Plot Height (m) verse Density in kg/m^3 below
----> 6 plt.plot(['Density_kg/m-3'], ['Height_m'], data = mississauga)
      7 plt.xlabel('Air Density (kg m^3)', fontsize = 16)
      8 plt.ylabel('Height (m)', fontsize = 16)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py:3575, in plot(scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   3567 @_copy_docstring_and_deprecators(Axes.plot)
   3568 def plot(
   3569     *args: float | ArrayLike | str,
   (...)
   3573     **kwargs,
   3574 ) -> list[Line2D]:
-> 3575     return gca().plot(
   3576         *args,
   3577         scalex=scalex,
   3578         scaley=scaley,
   3579         **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}),
   3580         **kwargs,
   3581     )
```

Etc.

I've checked for spelling, case sensitivity, comma placement, everything I can reasonably think of that could be screwing up my output here. Probably double-checked that the variable terms are spelled correctly a dozen times now. I've already run the data frame for this site and everything looks accurate, so I'm really confused here. Maybe someone more experienced can make a suggestion here?

Thanks!

Comment: The code in your traceback doesn't match the code in your snippet.  The traceback has the strings inside lists.  That's the problem.

Comment: Your title isn't well written. First, you don't necessarily have anything to do with 'JupyterHub' here. It would run and cause same issue on Jupyter installed locally and used only by one person. 'Coding issue' would probably be applicable to 99% of posts on here. [The 'How do I ask a good question?' guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) has an entire sub-section entitled 'Write a title that summarizes the specific problem'. You should follow that as a guide in the future.

Comment: @TimRoberts  Yes I noticed that afterwards, I was trying to mess around with it to see if maybe it belonged in a list?  Thank you though!  Ultimately managed to get it to work.

Comment: @Wayne  Duly noted, thanks!  I'll try to remember to check that in future.  I don't actually know really anything (at all!) about coding, so I apologize for any ambiguity on my end, I was just trying to give context as well as I could despite my lack of proficiency in this area.